# Can't view PDF in Chrome (using Acrobat Reader) unless I select "Inspect element"

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe-reader

Respective versions:

Chrome: 32.0.1700.76 m
Acrobat Reader: 11.0.06
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise (64-bit)

I use the Acrobat plugin (rather than Chrome's default PDF reader) because there are features that only it provides, such as seeing the document bookmarks.

A day or two ago Chrome crashed on me. Since then, trying to view PDFs in Chrome brings up a black screen; only if I right-click and select "Inspect element" will the PDF come up properly.

Any suggestions? (Tried repairing Reader, as per techie007's suggestion - no luck. Same also with wiping the Chrome profile, as per Ramhound's suggestion.)

Comment: Which OS is in question? Have you tried repairing and/or reinstalling Chrome and/or Reader yet?

Comment: First step would be to wipe the Chrome profile to see if the problem will fix itself.  If you want the data backup the profile before you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the OS you are using, there is a bunch of fixes, that's for sure. You can also simply install this add-ons and that will do.

[Google PDF/PPT Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn)

> *Automatically previews pdfs, powerpoint presentations, and other documents in Google Docs Viewer.
>   By clicking on a link for a supported document format you'll be taken to the Google Docs Viewer.  No more downloading large files and launching another application just to view it.*
>
> *The Google Docs Viewer does not work on files that require a log-in to
>   view, but you can make it ignore specific domains in the options so
>   you will still download the file.*

Give it a shot

Hope this helps.